# Is it safe to mount a medium-sized air compressor to the floor to stop or limit vibrations?

Tags: tools, safety, mounting, compressor

I have a 220V 6hp 33gal oil-less horizontal air compressor that aside from being noisy rattles all over the floor.

Stock Image:

[image]

I would like to either mount it to the floor or build a small frame/box for it to sit in tightly. I have a permanent location for it but want to make sure it "shaking" isn't a safety/stabilizing factor for the compressor/motor. The compressor was just rebuilt with all new seals/gaskets, sits on a concrete pad, and moves up to ~ 1 foot in a single cycle. The floor is only about 3 degrees off grade, a soft ball won't even roll, but the compressor obviously favors that direction which is away from the wall.

Also very open to other mounting or generic solution.

Answer (score 4):

If the compressor is equipped with anchoring tabs it can be anchored to the floor. Install some pieces of rubber between the floor and the mounting tabs. Cut the rubber pieces from and old tire,rubber mat etc. Use locking nuts on the anchor bolts and don't tighten them so much that the rubber is completely compressed. If there are not mounting tabs on the compressor than I would build a wood box will restrict the wheels and what ever else hits the floor. Then anchor the box to the concrete pad.

Comment: To me, this sounds similar to the concept of a car's motor mounts. Would you agree your statement is to dampen and not forcibly stop the vibrations?

Comment: Yes, you want to damp the vibrations with an isolator such as rubber feet. Otherwise, you're still putting a large vibratory force on the mounting points, which will wear them out over time. For a dramatic example of an underdamped system, [here's a Chinook destroying itself via ground resonance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LFLV47VAbI). Now with a compressor you're not going to get vibratory loads of nearly that magnitude, but you'll still place unnecessary wear on your compressor.